# under what circumstances $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{ f(x) + g(x) \} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{f(x) \} + \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{g(x)\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f$ and $g$ be real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

As we know that the elementary property of supremum of functions is
$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{ f(x) + g(x) \} \leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{f(x) \} + \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{g(x)\}. $$

I'm curious about under what circumstances the equality will hold? I thought constant functions $f,g$ could make it to be equal. What else?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the maxima of $f,g$ are at the same point, it holds.

Comment: Since $f$ and $g$ are not necessarily continuous, I guess there won't be a necessary condition for the equality.

Comment: @ThePortakal What if $f$ and $g$ are both continuous, then how to make the equality hold? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is equivalent to:

for each $n\in \mathbb Z ^+$:  $f^{-1}(\sup(f)-\frac{1}{n},\sup f]\cap g^{-1}(\sup(g)-\frac{1}{n},\sup g ]\neq \varnothing$

Comment: What happens if $f=1$ and $\sup g = + \infty.$

Equality holds but not your condition $g^-1 (+\infty , +\infty ]  = \emptyset$

Comment: I was assuming finite supremum

Answer (score 1):

One can be $f,g$  be monotone functions of same type. 
and It doesn't have to be strictly monotone!  This even covers all constant functions

Another one can be  only $f$  be a constant function , No condition on $g$

Comment: There are other cases making equality.

Comment: Definitely, I  don't claim  necessary and sufficient @coffeemath

Comment: @coffeemath Could you give us some examples making equality? thanks

Comment: @Paradiesvogel  Another type example, given $f \ge 0,$ is to use $g=kf$ for some $k>0.$

Comment: @Redshoes Would you mind to explain what does "$f, g$ be monotone functions of same type"? did you mean that $f$ and $g$ are either both monotone increasing or both monotone decreasing? Many thanks again :-)